# Scalaxb reads from XML, invokes "label", receives UnsupportedOperationException - why?

Tags: xml, scala, xsd, xsd-validation, scalaxb

I'm using scalaxb to convert an instance of XML into another object as follows:

```
val x = xml.XML.load(inputStream)
println(x)

val ed = scalaxb.fromXML[entityDescriptor.scalaxb.EntityDescriptorType](x)
println(ed)
```

When it invokes `fromXML`, I receive the following exception:

```
scalaxb.ParserFailure: Error while parsing 
    urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol 
    urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol 
    urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol: 
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
    class Group does not support method 'label'
```

The XML is well-formed and valid, according to Java's built-in XML Schema validator (I'm converting from a Java to a Scala project).

From my own investigation, it appears that somewhere in scalaxb, it has created an instance of [`scala.xml.Group`](http://harrah.github.io/browse/samples/library/scala/xml/Group.scala.html), and it has invoked the `label` method, which for `Group`, has no implementation.

1. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?
2. If it is a bug, is there a workaround?
3. If it is not a bug, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a scalaxb bug. Please open a Github issue. http://scalaxb.org/issue-reporting-guideline

Comment: Thanks Eugene! Will do.